# How to maintain cscope database in git repo

Tags: git, vim, cscope

I just started using cscope but after switching between git branches, I seem to have made the old database stale.

How can I can more easily keep my cscope databse up to date?

One option seems to adjust the githooks to run a small script:

```
post-checkout
post-commit
post-merge
```

Another alternative is to make an alias to do something every time I open vim:

In `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias cvim='cscope -Rqb && vim'
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cscope.1.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/K8-AZ4VVHns

Comment: If you don't want to enter the interactive mode in cscope, you can run it with the `-b` flag

Answer (score 1):

Your githooks idea sounds good to me.

Or you could use a file watcher (like [entr](http://www.entrproject.org/)) to run cscope every time a file changes in your project or in a specific part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could set a timed vim script to fire which would check if the git branch has changed, and if so trigger a cscope rebuild?

You can probably use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the current git branch in your timed vim script, then compare it to the previously retrieved value.